# $e^x-x-4$equating with zero

Tags: special-functions, inverse

I want to find out the values of x where the $f(x) = e^x-x-4$ will equal zero.

My problem by solving this myself is that I cannot use logarithm natural (ln) because I have a normal x:

$f(x) = e^x - x - 4$

$f(x) = 0 $

$\Rightarrow e^x - x -4 = 0 (| +x | +4)$

$\Rightarrow e^x = x + 4$

Failed solution one:
$ e^x = x + 4 | ^{(-x)}$

$ e^0 = (x + 4)^{(-x)}$

$1 = (x + 4)^{(-x)}$
    ?

Failed solution two:

$e^x = x + 4 | \ln$

$\Rightarrow x = \ln(x) + \ln(4)$
    ?

What is the solution?

Cheers bodo

Comment: In your failed solution two, you can't say $\ln(x+4)=\ln(x)+\ln(4)$.

Comment: To get more intuition try to solve $e^x = x+4$ by plotting the curves.  You can see that positive solution will be between 1 and 2, and negative one will be around -4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of equations generally have no closed-form solution.

It is often possible to manipulate the equation into a form that allows a solution to be written in terms of [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but that's usually not a major improvement from a practical point of view.

You will need to approximate the solution numerically.

---

Solution with $W$: Set $y = -e^x$. Then $x-e^x = -4$ becomes
$$ \log(-y)+y = -4 $$
Exponentiating both sides get
$$ -ye^y = e^{-4} $$
so by definition of the $W$ function we have $y=W(-e^{-4})$. Plug into the definition of $y$ and we get
$$ x = \log(-W(-e^{-4}))$$
which produces one solution for each of the two branches of $W$. Enlightening, right?

Comment: thank you for the answer. Than I will have to get the answer through simplification and test insertion.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a numerical solution, then there are many methods available.  For example, Newton's Method converges quite rapidly on each root.  First, if $f(x) = e^x - x - 4$, then $f'(x) = e^x - 1$.  Since $f'$ has only the root $x=0$, we can infer that $f$ has at most two roots, one on either side of $0$.  Set up the recursive formula for Newton's Method:
$$
  x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{e^{x_n} - x_n - 4}{e^{x_n}-1}.
$$
With initial guess $x_0 = -4$, and 4 iterations, we find a solution stable to 14 decimal digits: $-3.98133937091132$.  With initial guess $x_0=2$, we get:
$1.74903138601270$ (stable to 14 digits after 6 iterations).